# Are there documented Arduino class or file name restrictions?

Tags: compilation-errors, compiler

I ran into a strange problem were the compiler could not find a header file that I knew existed.

The problem was I created a class called ArduinoEvent and put it in ArduinoEvent.hpp,  but when I tried to include it in a client file, the compiler complained that the file did not exist.

```
In file included from sketch/NetworkConnection.hpp:4:0,
                 from /home/john/development/arduino/esp_pump_monitor/app.ino:4:
sketch/MyEvent.h:5:28: fatal error: ArduinoEvent.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "ArduinoEvent.hpp"
                            ^
```

After realizing that the compiler copies the files into another directory,  I took a look and found that it had copied the `ArduinoEvent.hpp` file to 
`ArduinoEvent.hpp.cpp`.  Since all the other files were copied fine, I simply renamed the file to `BrduinoEvent.hpp` and then everything was fine.

After searching I could not find anything that would imply that I could not name a class / file ArduinoBlah, so I was going to open an issue, but wanted to see if this restriction was documented somewhere and I just could not find it.

### Update

I originally *assumed* the problem was due to the file being called ArduinoXxxx, but I hit this again with another file.  I think the issue is related to the files being in the "top" folder.  I noticed the process copies the xxx.ino files to xxx.ino.cpp,  so I think that's what is happening and somehow it thinks various files are .ino files while they are not.  As a workaround I moved all my class files to a `lib` folder and include them from there `#include "./lib/xxx.hpp"` for example.  This seems to be working.

Comment: A partial answer may be found at: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Build-Process

Comment: Try renaming `*.hpp` → `*.h`.

Comment: same thing happens,  but if I use the name .cpp or even include an empty .cpp file it seems ok